# Import Math Module on Aptana Studio 3

Tags: python

I am using Aptana Studio 3 to self-learn Python. Now I try to write a program that solves quadratic equations and I need to use the sqrt() function from math module. However, as I try to import math, the compiler shows that this is an "Unused import". I then try to download and install the module online but can't find any sources that seem to solve this problem. I wish you could help, thanks!

Comment: If you import math, it will show as an unused import *until you use it.* :-)

Comment: I did try to use sqrt() after importing math but aptana can't recognize it and shows it's a "undefined variable".

Comment: If you `import math` then you have to call it like `math.sqrt()`. If you want to call it like `sqrt()` you will need to do `from math import sqrt` instead. In any case, `** .5` (to the half power) is probably easier and requires no imports.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks!